# Installation of Ionic brings in some unusual errors in windows x64

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, installation

When I wanted to Install and work on Ionic, I had to install other things like Android SDK, and set some path variables. I did all of them. I installed Cordova using the code

`npm install -g cordova`

Now when I try to install ionic using a similar command as follows

```
npm install -g ionic
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 172.16.0.19:8080
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm-debug.log
```

What should I do now to install ionic. What could be the possible reason for the above error?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to install the  nodejs(v4.4.x or above) on your system.      https://nodejs.org/en/ avoid v6.1.x as ionic may not be compatible with it for now.

and try the below mentioned command.

use command

```
npm install -g ionic@beta cordova
```

for getting ionic 2 installed on your system.

and also make sure npm is up to date

on

```
npm -v
```

you should get v3.8.6 or greater

AND **MAKE SURE THERE IS NO PROXY SET ON YOUR SYSTEM, because npm dont not work behind proxies**

**I think the main reason behing your error is PROXY , go to your proxy settings and disable proxy.**

2.Now if the error message continue there is some issue with the PATH.
Make sure you have given correct path for android SDK , java , gradle and nodejs.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But considering your above answers, the best one matching my problem is that I have a older version of npm. But even if I upgrade npm using the command, "npm install npm", the same problem occurs. Please correct me if I'm wrong in my code. How shall I upgrade my npm?

Comment: try using **npm install -g npm**  and don not use node v6.1.x for now , go with a lower version like node v5.11.x

Comment: happy to get a comment from you! Thanks., will get back shortly :) @ritesh_bhat

Answer (score 0):

Finally I achieved it. Though it was simple, it is a common mistake that we all commit I guess!

Disabling the proxy in system was not sufficient.
I was not able to delete the proxy using the following commands

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Instead using the following command helped.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=null
set HTTPS_PROXY=null
```

[Reference Done here](http://luxiyalu.com/how-to-remove-all-npm-proxy-settings/)